# Uploading an image to a Rails server via an Ember.js app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, paperclip

Like it says on the tin, I'm trying to upload an image with my Ember.js app to a Rails backend that's using Paperclip to manage file uploads. I had a look around and couldn't see any simple way to do this, does anyone know of a good solution here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced similar recently, and it turns out that there are lots of complications with file uploading - does the device support it, do you want to be able to style the input that triggers the upload, etc.

We opted for Jquery File Upload: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload

The approach I took was to upload directly to S3 from the browser, and then set the token that S3 returns as a property on a model, then save that to the server. Then on the server, you set off a background job to pull in that file from S3 and put it where it should be.

Comment: why didn't you just leave it in S3?

Comment: Because it needed processing - resizing etc.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a fairly simple ember.js file upload example a few months back that shows how you can write a custom view + a custom adapter that allows you to post a multipart form back to the server. The example I did is built for python / django but the concepts should apply

https://github.com/toranb/ember-file-upload

I recently upgraded this to RC1 (like 5 minutes ago) and it appears to still work :D

Comment: Is a custom adapter neccessary for file upload?

Comment: not 100% but you do need some code (model or adapter) to serialize the form data and post it

Answer (score 1):

There is now an [Ember Uploader](https://github.com/benefitcloud/ember-uploader) plugin for Ember. I'm just in the process of integrating it right now.

I have a couple kinks I'm ironing out, but it seems pretty legit. Probably less configuration than using the jquery file upload.